# How to add events to Google Calendar using FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying in my FullCalendar add events to my google calendar, followed the example below, 
[How to add events to Google Calendar using FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717886/how-to-add-events-to-google-calendar-using-fullcalendar/30715765#30715765)

but does not work me, if anyone knows how to do please help.

this my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'/>
   <link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
   <link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>
   <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
   <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
   <script src='../gcal.js'></script>
   <script>

      $(document).ready(function () {

         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            var eventData, title;
            select: function(start, end) {
                title = prompt('Event Title:');
               },
               editable: true
            }


               if (title) {
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                     {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                     },
                     true // make the event "stick"
                 );
                   // Now we push it to Google also :
                   add_event_gcal(title,start,end);  
                }
             }
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

         });

      });

      /****** NOW WE ASK THE EVENT TO BE PUSHED TO GOOGLE **************/
      function add_event_gcal(title,start,end) {
         alert(title);
         // I will create the eventInsert script in a new page, and I name it here :
         var url = "php/calendrier_add.php",
             data = {'titre_event' :title, 'start' : start, 'end' :end};

         // I want to check in the page the result of what happened
         $('#gcal_loader').load(url,data,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "error") alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
         });
      }

   </script>

   <style>

      body {
         margin: 40px 10px;
         padding: 0;
         font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
      }

      #loading {
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
         top: 10px;
         right: 10px;
      }

      #calendar {
         max-width: 900px;
         margin: 0 auto;
      }

   </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='loading'>loading...</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is file php

```
 <?php

// variables can only be got with $_REQUEST ?
$titre_event = $_REQUEST['titre_event'];
$start = $_REQUEST['start'];
$end = $_REQUEST['end'];
$allday = $_REQUEST['allday'];


/*$where_event = $_REQUEST['where_event'];
$content_event = $_REQUEST['content_event'];*/


/********************************************
        GOOGLE API CONNECTION
********************************************/

    /************************************************
      Make an API request authenticated with a service account.
     ************************************************/
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../google/autoload.php');// or wherever autoload.php is located
    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../google/autoload.php');

    /************************************************
      The name is the email address value provided  as part of the service account (not your  address!)
      cf. : https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your account>
     ************************************************/
    $client_id = '1020443454327******'; // YOUR Client ID
    $service_account_name ='102044345*****'; // Email Address in the console account

    $key_file_location = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../google/Mi proyecto-edc74d9206de.p12'); // key.p12 to create in the Google API console
    echo "key".$key_file_location;

    if (strpos($client_id, "googleusercontent") == false || !strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
        echo "no credentials were set.";
        exit;
    }

    /** We create service access ***/
    $client = new Google_Client();  

    /************************************************
    If we have an access token, we can carry on.  (Otherwise, we'll get one with the help of an  assertion credential.)
    Here we have to list the scopes manually. We also supply  the service account
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'), // ou calendar_readonly
    $key
);

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

/********************************************
        END OF GOOGLE API CONNECTION
********************************************/

/*********** AT LAAAAST, WE PUSH THE EVENT IN GOOGLE CALENDAR ***************/
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// We get the calendar
$calendarId = 'qv8rv593gn5g8pumu0bid6bco0@group.calendar.google.com'; // or whatever calendar you like where you have editable rights


    /************* INSERT ****************/
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => $titre_event, 
    //'location' => $where_event,
   // 'description' => $content_event,
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $start, //'2015-06-08T15:00:00Z'
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => $end,
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
    ),
    /* in case you need that :
    'attendees' => array(
        array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
        array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
    ),*/
    'reminders' => array(
        'useDefault' => FALSE,
        'overrides' => array(
            array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 20)
    ),
        ),
));

$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s', $event->htmlLink);

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors while trying to add events to google calendar?

Comment: I have no answer, I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples

1)

```js
//Global variables to access the calendar
     clientId = 'Your cliendID',
     scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
     calendarId = 'Your google calendar id',
     eventsList = [];


//Autorice the user
    checkAuth();

      //authorization in google
      function checkAuth() {
         gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
               'client_id': clientId,
               'scope': scopes,
               'immediate': true
            }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      //checks if authorized
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

         if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
            loadCalendarApi();
         } else {
            handleAuthClick();
         }
      }

      //request credentials
      function handleAuthClick() {
         gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
               client_id: clientId,
               scope: scopes,
               immediate: false
            }, handleAuthResult);
         return false;
      }

     function loadCalendarApi() {

         gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', makeApiCall);

      }`
```

2)

```js
// Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
      


function makeApiCall() {

         requestList = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': calendarId
         });

         console.log('--- eventsList ---');
         console.log(eventsList);
         uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventsList);
         eventsList = [];

         // Step 6: Execute the API request
         requestList
            .then(function (resp) {

               if (resp.result.error) {

                  reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);

               } else if (resp.result.items) {

                  resp.result.items.forEach(function (entry, index) {
                     eventsList.push({
                        id: entry.id,
                        title: entry.summary,
                        start: entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date, // try timed. will fall back to all-day
                        end: entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date, // same
                        url: url,
                        location: entry.location,
                        description: entry.description
                     });
                  });

               }

               if (eventsList.length > 0) {
                  uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventsList, true);
               }

            }, function (reason) {
               console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
            });
      }`
```

3)

```js
//insert into calendar



      function makeRpcRequest(eventData) {

         gapi
            .client
            .load('calendar', 'v3')
            .then(function () {
               request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                  'calendarId': calendarId,
                  'resource': eventData
               });

               request.then(function (resp) {

                  if (resp.result.error) {
                     reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);
                  } else {

                     makeApiCall();
                     console.log(resp);
                     var creator = resp.result.creator.email;
                     var calendarEntry = resp.result.htmlLink;

                     console.log('--- Calendar entry successfully created by---');
                     console.log(creator);
                     console.log('--- dd ---');
                     console.log(calendarEntry);
                  }
               }, function (reason) {
                  console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);

               });
            });
      }`
```

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, I tried to use your code but I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined`