# Get events from fullcalendar to display on google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Currently, I am using fullcalendar for adding events in my web application.Then I want to get all events in fullcalendar to display in my google calendar.

But I have tried to search and I am also try with  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589777/how-to-add-events-to-google-calendar-using-fullcalendar)

I got error `ReferenceError: uiCalendarConfig is not defined`. I don know how to fix this problem.I try to find another solution but it seems to much difficult.

my fullcalendar look like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //..........
});
```

This is code I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var clientId = '######',
     scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
     calendarId = '#####';


    var apikey = '#####';

    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Step 2: Reference the API key
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apikey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
    }


  //authorization in google
  function checkAuth() {
     gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
           'client_id': clientId,
           'scope': scopes,
           'immediate': true
        }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  //checks if authorized
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

     if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        loadCalendarApi();
     } else {
        handleAuthClick();
     }
  }

  //request credentials
  function handleAuthClick() {
     gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
           client_id: clientId,
           scope: scopes,
           immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
     return false;
  }

function loadCalendarApi() {

     gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', makeApiCall);

}

// Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.


function makeApiCall() {

     requestList = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': calendarId
     });

     console.log('--- eventsList ---');
     console.log(eventsList);
     //uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventsList);
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventsList);

     eventsList = [];

     // Step 6: Execute the API request
     requestList
        .then(function (resp) {

           if (resp.result.error) {

              reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);

           } else if (resp.result.items) {

              resp.result.items.forEach(function (entry, index) {
                 eventsList.push({
                    id: entry.id,
                    title: entry.summary,
                    start: entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date, // try timed. will fall back to all-day
                    end: entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date, // same
                    //url: url,
                    location: entry.location,
                    description: entry.description
                 });
              });

           }

           if (eventsList.length > 0) {
              //uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventsList, true);
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventsList, true);


           }

        }, function (reason) {
           console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
  }
```

During I am trying this code it is the same as I get events from google calendar to display in my fullcalendar it is not the same as what I want.
If anyone know or have experiences with this, help me please.

Thanks,

Comment: Share your codes please. :)

Comment: Ok I updated it , you can check my code again, thanks.

Comment: You may check this [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/). Hope it helps.