# How to embeded "full Calendar" in Google Sites by using Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, google-sites

I  Need to host a google website with Google Calendar feature, but it not looking Good. So Planning to Implement "Full Calendar". As I am new to this I am getting so many doubts after reading the Docs.

1. Where to copy the  required js/css files.
2. Where to write the code.
3. Where to host the Folder.

Even Docs not providing the above info for Beginners. It may be basic, but I fed up after extensive searching

Can anyone provide me the link from starting to end how to do this.

Comment: If you want to just navigate around (read) then fullcalender supports it [out of the box](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/) but you want it to behave like regular one with ability to add/edit/delete events then it becomes a bit more involved , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717886/how-to-add-events-to-google-calendar-using-fullcalendar) might help you if latter is your case :)

Comment: Hi Novice, Thank you very much for your reply. Actually in documentation they mentioned to provide reference files like fullcalendar.css etc, where to host those files in google sites? where to write the code. These are may be basic Questions, but I am new to this one please help me on this. Thanks, David

Comment: Many options are there 2 of the most used for google sites are 1.(best one) use CDNs like [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullcalendar) , you don't need to do anything just copy the css/js tag code in your html and it's done ! 2 the other option is to host your files on [google drive](http://www.getcooltricks.com/google/using-google-drive-to-host-css-and-js/)

Comment: Hi Novice.. Thank you very much for your reply.. I tried a lot to make it in google sites by using HTML Box but not taking the External cdnjs. Now Google Drive has with drawn the hosting feature .. Please help me on this to find any other way  to do this. once again thank you verymuch for your valuable time Thanks, David