# How do I add event from fullcalendarjs to google calendar on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have implemented fullcalendar gem in my rails app. But I am really confused about how to add the event from fullcalendar to different users' Google calendar. There's no clear guide on fullcalendar side as well. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717886/how-to-add-events-to-google-calendar-using-fullcalendar

Comment: there's no clear guidance because that's not a built-in feature of the calendar. You have to write your own code for that in order to call Google's Calendar API. You can of course use fullCalendar's callback hooks to detect when the user has created an event in fullCalendar, and go from there.

Comment: @noogui That question is in the context of php. I don't know PHP code, I am building this in rails

Comment: @ADyson do you mind showing me which one is the callback hook? Also, do you think it's a good idea to use zapier to send the info from fullcalendar to Google Calendar?

Comment: I don't know what zapier is or does so I can't comment on that, or whether it suits your use case. You can use ajax and the Google Calendar API to do it directly from the page where your calendar is, I do know that. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/ describes all the different callbacks you can use. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/ for instance is triggered when the user drags to select an area of the calendar on which to create a new event. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ describes the Google Calendar API.

Comment: If you make an attempt at this and get stuck please do post your code here with any errors so we can help to fix it.